# Javascript RegEx to detect browser

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to detect `opera safari firefox` browsers using a regex but Chrome also have `safari` in `userAgent` value so am trying to ignore `chrome` from `userAgent` as below but it isn't working, can someone help me out?

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isUnsupportedBrowser = (/(opera|safari|firefox|(?!chrome))\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i).test(userAgent);
```

Comment: You can use some trick: [browserhack.com](http://browserhacks.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only match UAs that don't contain `chrome` this should work:

```
/(?!.*chrome).*/i
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aN7wM7/1)

If you really want to validate that the UA contains `Opera`, `Firefox`, or `Safari` you can use the following:

```
/(?=.*(opera|safari|firefox))(?!.*chrome).*/i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to exclude Chrome use a regex that matches its UA:

```
var isUnsupportedBrowser = (/Chrome.*Safari/).test(userAgent);
```

If you instead want to match all the allowed UA, provide some test cases.